# Jackson - how to apply custom deserialization based on json content?

Tags: java, jackson

Let's say I have the following json:

```
{
    "first_path": "/just/a/path",
    "second_path": "/just/another/path",
    "relative_path": { "$relative": "some_file" },
}
```

And I have the class which I can not modify:

```
public class Paths {
    public String first_path;
    public String second_path;
    public String third_path; // Can't mark this with annotations
}
```

What I want is to apply some custom deserialization logic to ALL String values if they look like { "$...": "..." } in json. In my example I obviously was going to translate relative path to absolute based on some logic and put the absolute path to Paths.third_path member.

How I can achieve this with Jackson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending few hours, I've found the way of doing this by overriding String deserialization with following:

```
public class PathJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) 
                  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        JsonToken token = parser.getCurrentToken();
        if (token.equals(JsonToken.START_OBJECT)) {
            // This String value looks like an object - try to parse $relative
            Path path = parser.readValueAs(Path.class);
            return path.$relative;
        } else {
            // This is normal String value
            return parser.getText();
        }
    }
}
```

And Path class is:

```
public class Path {
    public String $relative;
}
```

The PathJsonDeserializer should be added to mapper through module as usual.
Is there any other more component approach? For the case if I have few $-based rules with different logic.